# I want to change some parameters of application.properties file in running application in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am using application.properties file for some static properties like username and password but I want to change those parameters without stopping my application I was trying this with actuators but I failed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Add a minimal code example for example.

Comment: I would recommend using spring cloud config server for such use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest to use Spring Cloud Config.

Here is a pretty good article about how this works:

https://nirajsonawane.github.io/2019/02/22/Update-Configs-Dynamically-Using-Spring-Cloud-Bus-and-Spring-Cloud-Config/